# Using the first two integers as the dimensions of the Array

Tags: java, arrays, file, text, txt

I'm supposed to take the first two integers from a txt file and create an array using them. Here is the txt file that was given to me.

5 is how many rows are in the array. 6 is how many columns are in the array. I started off with just trying to read the first integer but when I try to run it I get an error.
[image]

```
5
6
68 72 75 81 72 75
92 87 71 83 60 75
90 52 13 63 13 61
84 67 100 99 98 92
51 32 94 76 55 11
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File fileToRead = new File("array.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(fileToRead);
        int grades = input.nextInt();
        int[][] array = new int[grades][grades];

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            for (int row = 0; row < grades; row++) {
                for (int column = 0; column < grades; column++) {
                    array[row][column] = input.nextInt();
                }
            }
        }
        input.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.println(array[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm taking the right approach but this is what I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Good job!  Your code is close to correct.  The problem is that you aren't reading the second count, `6`, and so you are reading `5 * 5 = 25` integers from the file to fill out your array.  After doing this, there are still 5 numbers left to be read.  Because of this, and the line `while (input.hasNext())`, you then start over again and try to read another 25 numbers from the file.  This is what gets you into trouble, as there are not 25 more numbers to read.  If you take out the `while (input.hasNext())` line, your code will run.  If you read and use the `6`, your code should do exactly what you're hoping it will.

Here's a version of your code with just minor fixes that does the right thing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File fileToRead = new File("/tmp/data.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(fileToRead);
    int rows = input.nextInt();
    int cols = input.nextInt();
    int[][] array = new int[rows][cols];

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < cols; column++) {
            array[row][column] = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
    input.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            System.out.print(array[i][j]);
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
68 72 75 81 72 75 
92 87 71 83 60 75 
90 52 13 63 13 61 
84 67 100 99 98 92 
51 32 94 76 55 11
```

Comment: OMG! I just edited my code to look similar to yours literally a minute ago. The only difference is adding the space after each value.

A question I have now is, and is something I am confused with, this is supposed to be printed all on another class I was just writing it in my main class for testing purposes. How would I go about doing so?

Comment: There are many examples of how to do this.  Just google "java class example".  Here's one that I found right at the top that I think demonstrates what you need to know:  https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_classes.asp

Comment: Actually, that one seems kinda lame.   Here's a better one:  https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/class-objects

Comment: So what we did was correct actually, I have another class with a printArray() method, how do I accept the 2D array in this method ?

Comment: Just define the method as taking `int[][] array`.  You can get the sizes with `array.length` and array[0].length`